# Mongo-Hadoop connector issue

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

I run file jar Word Count but have this error

`NoClassDefFoundError: org/Apache/commons/lang/StringUtils ..`

[image]

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.util.MongoConfigUtil.getMongoURIs(MongoConfigUtil.java:409)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.util.MongoConfigUtil.getOutputURIs(MongoConfigUtil.java:598)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(MongoOutputFormat.java:32)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:277)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1568)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1568)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1589)
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Comment: You need `apache-commons` in either `wc.jar` or on your classpath.

Comment: Compile your code into a "fat jar"

Comment: pls,can u teamview help me ?